# how can I make the client talk to the express server?

Tags: javascript, express, server

So I am trying to link this interface to a server so that the message I input in the front end is Posted in a separate webpage hosted on the server. eg "Hello [name]"

This is the interface:

```
<form id="loginformA" action="userlogin" method="post">
<div>
    <label for="Insert message here">Message: </label>
    <input type="text" id="message" name="message"></input>
</div>
```

and this is the server I am trying to post the message to:

```
 var express = require('express');

 var app = express();

 app.use(express.static('public'));

 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

 app.use(bodyParser.json());

 app.post("/userlogin", function(request, response) {
 response.send( "Hello " + request.body.message );
    });

 app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, process.env.IP);
```

I am just not sure how to make the interface and server talk to each other. I would also like to store all the messages in a db too, but that is for later after I figure this out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your form submits to /userlogin. You should define that route in your server like this:

```
app.post('/userlogin', function(req, res){
res.send('Hello' + req.body.message);
}
```

req.body is basically the post data submitted by your form, in this case only the input named 'message.'

any time you wish to submit a form to a node server, ensure the action corresponds to a route or method with an identical name.

Answer (score 0):

From your html ...

```
 app.post('/userlogin', function(request, response) {
    response.send( "Welcome, your message is: " + request.body.message );
 });
```